# Spotfire Information Link Filters

Tags: spotfire

Does anybody know how to filter out data using the Information Link filters (for example: certain OID values from a column).  The filter seems to work by including the values specified and removing everything else?  Thanks - Grant

Comment: You are correct in your assumption, but I have found that this is usually easier accomplished in other ways. Mind if I ask what your use case is? i.e. will these values change by input from the user, or are they static, or...? Just elaborate a bit on your question and I think we can give you some really solid options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use custom SQL feature of Information Link. Simply follow the Steps below

1. Edit Infolink
2. Click SQL
3. In [Edit SQL Dialogue](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/spotfire/6.5.3/doc/html/id/id_details_on_edit_sql.htm) insert your filter condition. e.g. *and OID not in ('xyz', 'abc')*
4. Click OK
5. Save

The details on how to edit an Infolink SQL can be found in  [TIBCO Documentation here](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/spotfire/6.5.3/doc/html/id/id_editing_the_sql_of_an_information_link.htm).